# Position activereport section to new page dynamically

Tags: activereports

Am facing a little trouble with active reports..
Mine is a report with 20-30 pages with titles and explanations.
under each of the titles there is an image and after that the explanation comes.
So this is like page by page continuously. So each of the pages contains multiples titles and explanations of that. THis is as on the detail section of my report.

But the issue is, in some pages title shows on the bottom of the page and the image and explanation getting moved to the next page since there is no space on that page after the title to accommodate image and explanation. So my question is, is that possible for me to move that part where title is almost at the edge of the pages to the new page. So that that title, image and explanation comes in new page which fixes that awkward feeling.

Requesting your kind attention since this is an emergency requirement in my project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're concerned about is that the title is getting split from the rest of the content you can set the KeepTogether property on your section to True, this will cause ActiveReports to try to place all of the content on the same page.

However, in this case you want to add a page break when the content for that section begins at an arbitrary point down on the page.

To do this, you can keep track of the section's top in relation to the page. If it's greater than a certain value, enable a pagebreak control, otherwise keep the pagebreak control disabled.  ActiveReports 6 SP2 added the [CurrentLocation](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/webframe.html?topic4456.html) property which can be used to get the location of the section on the page.

There's nothing built-in to handle this. you'd need to keep track of section heights in the BeforePrint events, incrementing a height counter of sorts.

Comment: Sorry for late replying.The problem with keep together is even if the content is starting from half of the page, it will moved to the new page to make to all together in one page. So there will be a blank area after that text before the next one. But in my case if the section starts after  75th or 80th percent of the page, it should move to next page dynamically. So it could save that one or two lines get fall on the bottom of a previous page. Hope you got my problem.

Comment: Which version of ActiveReports are you using?  ActiveReports 6 Service Pack 2 added a [CurrentLocation](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/webframe.html?topic4456.html) property which might be usable here.  It might be too late to use it for the current section, but you can use it on the previous one to add a page break control.  Let me refer a co-worker to this question to see if he can come up with a better answer.

Comment: Here is the advice from my coworkers.  I'll also update my answer.  They suggested that you keep track of the section's top in relation to the page. If it's greater than a certain value, enable a pagebreak control, otherwise keep the pagebreak control disabled.  There's nothing built-in to handle this. you'd need to keep track of section heights in the BeforePrint events, incrementing a height counter of sorts.

Comment: Thanks a lot James... I really hope that will help me to solve the issue... But I dont know the version of Active Reports installed on the server having SP2 in it.. Otherwise I will install it and try that way.. Will check on it and will let you know the result.. Ones again.. Thank you for your great support..

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an extra level of grouping to your report, such that there's a group for each title? Then you can use the new page before/after property to ensure each title gets its own page? Possible downside would be that every title would then get a new page, which might not be what you want